# OpenGL - Power Of Two Textures

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl

OpenGL uses power-of-two textures.
This is because some GPUs only accept power-of-two textures due to MipMapping. Using these power-of-two textures causes problems when drawing a texture larger than it is.

I had thought of one way to workaround this, which is to only use the PO2 ratios when we're making the texture smaller than it actually is, and using a 1:1 ratio when we're making it bigger, but will this create compatibility issues with some GPUs?

If anybody knows whether issues would occur (I cannot check this as my GPU accepts NPO2 Textures), or a better workaround, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your information is outdated. Arbitrary dimension textures are supported since OpenGL-2, which has been released in 2004. All contemporary GPUs do support NPOT2 textures very well, and without any significant performance penality.

There's no need for any workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for making this clearer. I have obviously been misinformed.